# How to describe Google Place ID using Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, google-places

I would like to describe [Google Place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) using [schema.org](/questions/tagged/schema.org) of a [MovieTheatre](https://schema.org/MovieTheater) entity.

I am assuming I should be using the [`sameAs`](https://schema.org/sameAs) property. However, what should be the Google Place ID?

Is it worth including this information for [seo](/questions/tagged/seo) purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Schema.org doesn’t offer a property for Google’s Place IDs. As these IDs are strings (not URIs), you can’t use the `sameAs` property.

I can see <del>two ways</del> one way how a Google Place ID could be specified:

- You could define your own property with the [`additionalProperty`](http://schema.org/additionalProperty) property, where you specify the Place ID as value for the [`value`](http://schema.org/value) property. Of course you can’t expect general consumers to make use of such a custom property.
- <del>You could use the [`hasMap`](http://schema.org/hasMap) property to link to the relevant Google Map (as far as I understand it, the URL would contain the Place ID).</del> The URL doesn’t seem to contain the Place ID; it seems to be used only in their APIs.

#### SEO

If you mean search features like rich results with "SEO purposes", there is typically no reason to guess: just check the search engine’s documentation, they should list which Schema.org properties have an effect.

In the case of Google Search, a page about a `MovieTheater` could qualify for a [Local Businesses rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-businesses) (but it doesn’t seem to be available for everyone yet). You can find the supported properties under [Local business properties](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-businesses#local_business_properties).